# Angular 4 Circular dependency detected

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-routing

Upgrading Angular Cli to 1.3.1 I have some warnings now

```
WARNING in Circular dependency detected: src\app\work-sessions\work-session-list\work-session-list.routing.ts
-> src\app\work-sessions\work-session-list\index.ts -> src\app\work
-sessions\work-session-list\work-session-list.routing.ts
```

Every class have a structure like this:

[image]

**work-session-list.routing.ts**

```
import { Route } from '@angular/router';
import { WorkSessionListComponent } from './index';

export const WorkSessionRoutes: Route[] = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: WorkSessionListComponent
  },
];
```

**Index.ts**

```
export * from './work-session-list.component';
export * from './work-session-list.routing';
```

**work-sessions-list.module.ts**

```
import { WorkSessionListComponent } from './work-session-list.component';
import { WorkSessionRoutes } from './work-session-list.routing';
import { DataTableModule } from 'primeng/primeng';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

@NgModule( {
    imports: [RouterModule.forChild( WorkSessionRoutes ), CommonModule , FormsModule],

    declarations: [WorkSessionListComponent],
    exports: [WorkSessionListComponent]
} )

export class WorkSessionListModule { }
```

Than in **app.routing.ts**

```
export const AppRoutes: Routes = [
      {
        path: 'workSession',
        loadChildren: './work-sessions/work-session-list/work-session-list.module#WorkSessionListModule'
      }
.
.
.
```

And in **app.module**

```
 @NgModule({
imports: [
CommonModule,
BrowserAnimationsModule,
FormsModule,
RouterModule.forRoot(AppRoutes),
 })
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ]
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

How can I solve this? It works but I have a lot of warnings

Answer (score 77, accepted):

As the warning says, `work-session-list.routing.ts` depends on `index.ts`:

```
import { WorkSessionListComponent } from './index';
```

And `index.ts` depends on `work-session-list.routing.ts`:

```
export * from './work-session-list.routing';
```

The first dependency is not necessary, since you could import `WorkSessionListComponent` directly from its source file:

```
import { WorkSessionListComponent } from './work-session-list.component';
```

This change should fix the problem.

Comment: So I can eliminate the index file?

Comment: `index.ts` files are known as `barrels`, which were useful before Angular2 R.C. 5 because there were no NgModules at that time. Barrels were the only solution to avoid countless imports / exports. Now that we have modules, they are obsolete. https://angular.io/guide/glossary#barrel

Comment: will it causes something wrong? I get the same warning after upgrading cli

Comment: @AlexBeugnet Using barrels is still useful while having NgModules!

Comment: Even with the existence of `ngModule` IMO index.ts is beneficial it sill avoid countless imports.

Comment: This is wrong solution. Barrel files should be used over deep imports.

Answer (score 4):

Ján Halaša answer is correct. I wanna explain some stuff to make things clear.

`index.ts` should not be removed, it should still be used.

I had the same problem, in my case I had a `cards` main modules with many submodules within it. (based on https://medium.com/@tomastrajan/the-best-way-to-architect-your-angular-libraries-87959301d3d3)

so in my `tsconfig.ts` I had

```
"@com-tuxin/cards/*": [
 "projects/cards/*",
 "projects/cards"
],
"@com-tuxin/cards": [
 "dist/cards/*",
 "dist/cards"
]
```

and under `projects/cards/src/lib` I have a directory for each off my modules, and each one of them has `index.ts` file.

the reason that I would get a circular dependencies warnings is because I would use barrels includes of a component in the same module that I'm in.

for example I had the sub-module `article-card`, and I had this code:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import {ArticleCardComponent} from '@com-tuxin/cards/src/lib/article-card';
import {MatCardModule} from '@angular/material/card';
import {MatButtonModule} from '@angular/material/button';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ArticleCardComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    MatCardModule,
    MatButtonModule,
  ],
  exports: [
    ArticleCardComponent
  ]
})
export class ArticleCardModule { }
```

so the problem is with `import {ArticleCardComponent} from '@com-tuxin/cards/src/lib/article-card;` since I'm in that exact module I should use exact path instead of barrels so I switched it with

```
import {ArticleCardComponent} from '@com-tuxin/cards/src/lib/article-card/article-card.component';
```

and that's it, problem is resolved.

and in my case in other libraries where I needed `article-card` component, I would just need to include `@com-tuxin/cards/src/lib/article-card` and I would get no circular dependencies.

hope this cleared things up.

Comment: The key statement for me here is, "since I'm in that exact module I should use exact path instead of barrels". That helped me get out of a bunch of barrel-based circular dependency warnings.