# Suppress "Circular dependency detected" suppress warning in Angular 6

Tags: angular, warnings, suppress-warnings

I get the warning

> Circular dependency detected!

in Angular 6 and I know why this problem appears, but it is not a problem at all.

I am currently working with SVG, and in my logic I prevent possible problems so I just want to suppress this warning. How can I do that?

I will fix this problem afterwards but for now I want to keep it because my code is more structured this way.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. When asking a question, you will get much better answers if you provide code. Add what you have tried so far. Also please check [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Just in case this helps anyone, I've been having the same issue even with the correct showCircularDependencies option set but I'm using custom-webpack. If you're using Angular 8 and custom-webpack, check out https://github.com/just-jeb/angular-builders/issues/422

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Here the right path into the angular.json file :

```
projects -> architect -> options - > "showCircularDependencies": false
```

Comment: Note, this is also working for a react project using nx. The only difference is the file named `workspace.json` instead of `angular.json`. Even the path in this big json is the same.

Comment: Also, if you're worried about losing the warning, you could configure a production-specific environment, and add it to that.

https://angular.io/guide/build#configuring-application-environments

Instead of 
`architect -> build -> options -> "showCircularDependencies": false`

You could do:
`architect -> build -> configurations -> myprodenvname -> "showCircularDependencies": false`

Comment: Although you'll need to be on version 8 or higher.

Answer (score 5):

It should be a problem, because it's like a recursive function with multiple components/modules. Ignoring the warning may cause a slow site, memory leaks, etc.

You may not notice anything at the moment, but it's bad practice, that you shouldn't get used to.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46113734/angular-4-circular-dependency-detected) is an example, how your circular dependency could be resolved.

**Edit:**

If you want to disable the warning completely, you can do that by [modifying](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/angular-cli) your `angular.json` config file.

```
"defaults": {
    "apps": {
      "showCircularDependencies": false
    }
    "build": {
      "showCircularDependencies": false
    }
  }
```

Comment: ok let me formulate this in another way. I am programming and I know that I have to eliminate this "warning" and I know how to do that. but for now I want to keep the warning because the code is more structured in this way.

Answer (score 2):

> projects -> architect -> options - > "showCircularDependencies": false

@Marcello is correct that is the corrrect path...however if running "ng serve" you need to make sure to stop (Ctrl+C) and restart it for your angular.json file to be loaded or you will still get the circular dependency warnings.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a custom webpack config using angular-builders, there is a workaround here:
https://github.com/just-jeb/angular-builders/issues/422

```
config.plugins = config.plugins.filter(plugin => !(plugin instanceof CircularDependencyPlugin));
    config.plugins.push(
        new CircularDependencyPlugin({
            exclude: /node_modules|shared/
        })
    );
```

I would also recommend just removing the plugin using the first line, as this feature is deprecated in newer angular versions