# Circular dependency detected Angular 6, main.ts

Tags: angular, typescript, circular-dependency

So, I have a function in main.ts

```
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';

import * as $ from 'jquery'

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
  .catch(err => console.log(err));

export function view_user(id) {
  ...some jQuery stuff
}
```

I use this function inside a component like this:

```
import { view_user } from 'src/main';
...
show_user(id){
    view_user(id)
}
```

and I am getting this warning:

> Circular dependency detected: src/app/profile/profile.component.ts ->
>   src/main.ts -> src/app/app.module.ts -> src/app/app-routing.module.ts
>   -> src/app/profile/profile.component.ts

Comment: Yes, Angular checks circular dependencies which are a sign of a code smell. Put view_user as a static method in a service class I'd say.

Comment: good idea :p i'll try that later :) thanks!

Comment: you can also choose to suppress the warning : Have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/a/51728842/2435263