# circular dependency angular shared module and index

Tags: angular, angular6

I am getting a Circular dependancy error like this - `src/app/shared/shared.module.ts -> src/app/shared/index.ts -> src/app/shared/shared.module.ts`

index.ts
`export * from './layout/index';
export * from './shared.module';`

shared.module.ts
`@NgModule({
exports: [
    CommonModule,
    NgSelectModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    BsDropdownModule,
    BsDatepickerModule,
    Ng4GeoautocompleteModule,
    RouterModule,
    NgxHmCarouselModule,
    NgxSpinnerModule,
    CarouselModule,
    AccordionModule,
    AngularGooglePlaceModule,
    ModalModule,
    ProgressbarModule,
    HeaderComponent,
    FooterComponent,
    SidebarComponent,
    PopoverModule,
    RatingModule,
    AgmCoreModule,
    NumberDirective,
    BootModalComponent,
    ErrorModalComponent,
  ]`

I am unable to find the circular dependency here. Please help.

Comment: Check out this. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46113734/angular-4-circular-dependency-detected

Comment: @HimanshuShekhar yeah, I checked that. But in my case 
shared.module.ts depends on the index.ts and index.ts depends on shared.module.ts. the 2nd dependency will be there otherwise it'll throw error. But don't know about the 1st one

Comment: Thanks, @HimanshuShekhar. I just solved it as it the header, footer and sidebar component was getting called.